How to use multiple databases in a single Django app?
I'm trying to set up my Django application to use multiple databases within a single app.
I have defined different database in my settings.py
I have only one app polls.
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mypage',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    },
    'ringi_db':{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'ringi',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    },
}


I have added mapping in settings.py
DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING = {
    'ringi':'ringi_db',
}

database router is defined like this
class dbrouter:
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'polls':
            return 'ringi_db'
        else:
            return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'polls':
            return 'ringi_db'
        else:
            return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'polls' or obj2._meta.app_label == 'polls':
           return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label == 'polls':
            return db == 'ringi_db'
        return None


models.py
#### Book table should be stored in  mypage db ####
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publication_date = models.DateField()
    isbn = models.CharField(max_length=13)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'book'

# Member table should be stored in ringi db #
class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'member'
        app_label = 'polls'


When i run python manage.py makemigrations polls only migration for book is being created.
I have read other answer from here and i am confused about app_label which seems like it should be same as name of the app. Please tell me where i am making mistake ?

If you only have one application named "polls" then what is "ringi" that your database router is referring to?

my bad, I updated the question. problem is how will i make sure that during migration, Member table will be migrated to 'ringi' database. I hope i am making sense. thank you.

That answer you linked to won't work because Django only creates migrations for apps that are present in INSTALLED_APPS see the duplicate target for a much simpler solution.
